# Статические файлы CSS Django

Tags: html, python, django

Не могу подключить статические файлы к шаблонам HTML в Django.
Я новичок в Django и не особо в это вник, но, однако, на моём прошлом тестовом проекте всё работало как надо.

Прошу помощи!

settings.py

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

base.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>{% block title %}Мой блог{% endblock %}</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'static/css/style_option.css' %}">

</head>

<body>
 {% block header %}{% endblock %}
 {% block content %}{% endblock %}
 {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

Расположение директорий(я не знаю как сделать это в виде текстовой структуры на форуме)
[image]

urls.py
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

urls.py приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жду ваших ответов!

Comment: Ждём ваших вопросов! Что, где и как не работает-то?

Comment: Укажите в настройках `STATIC_ROOT`, затем соберите статику командой `python manage.py collectstatic` и раздайте её, используя `urls.py` или любой `frontend` сервер (например, `Nginx`).

Comment: У меня css не подключается к шаблонам, в этом и есть проблема

Comment: STATIC_ROOT не помогает

Comment: @Gasplyak `urls.py` покажите

Comment: обновил, посмотрите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я разобрался со своей проблемой.
Объясню, в чём была вся суть, а всё было довольно просто:

Я нашёл информацию о том, что лучше всего держать директории с HTML-шаблонами и static файлами на одном уровне с manage.py, имеется ввиду то, что они должны находится вне директорий приложений. Конечно, можно в каждом приложении создавать по одной папке с шаблонами, статикой и прочим, но это может вызвать проблемы, как в моём случае к примеру.
Для теста я решил создать новый проект Django и, какого было моё удивление, когда я понял, что проблема всё-таки крылась как раз в расположении директорий.

Так что вопрос был довольно прост в решении, и это главное.

Всем спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 0):

у тебя неправильно указан путь к статик файлам. Твоя проблема в темплейте. 
Правильный путь к елементам папки css в папке static:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style_option.css' %}">
```

Comment: нет, дело не в этом. путь я конечно поменял и пробовал множество вариаций пути. вся суть в расположении файлов, но никак не могу понять, как верно их расположить, чтобы работало ровно.

Comment: а ты после того как обновлял путь, кеш обновлял? ctrl+shift+R